# Joining extract (day from DATE) on generate_series in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to generate a cumulative sales amounts by day of the month (so that I can graph multiple months on the same chart, with day of month on X axis and cumulative sum of amount on Y axis), but when I LEFT join onto generate_series(1,31), I'm getting:

```
d   sum
1   3746.5
2   5731.5
3   9258.42
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
d   sum
1   3746.5
2   5731.5
3   9258.42
4   0
5   0
... 0
31  0
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    d,
    SUM (SUM("Amount")) OVER (ORDER BY "CloseDate" ASC)
FROM
    salesforce."Opportunity"
LEFT JOIN generate_series (1, 31) d ON d = EXTRACT (DAY FROM "CloseDate")
WHERE
    EXTRACT (MONTH FROM "CloseDate") = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM now())
AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM "CloseDate") = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM now())
AND "StageName" = 'Closed Won'
AND "Type" = 'Renewal'
GROUP BY
    "CloseDate",
    d
```

I can feel that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Any help would be appreciated - thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. You need to put your aggregate in subquery and first select from generate_series then left join on that:

```
WITH days as (
        select d from generate_series (1, 31) d),
    aggregates as (
        SELECT
            EXTRACT (DAY FROM "CloseDate") d,
            SUM (SUM("Amount")) OVER (ORDER BY "CloseDate" ASC) total
        FROM
            salesforce."Opportunity"
        WHERE
            EXTRACT (MONTH FROM "CloseDate") = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM now())
            AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM "CloseDate") = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM now())
            AND "StageName" = 'Closed Won'
            AND "Type" = 'Renewal'
        GROUP BY
            "CloseDate"
     )
select days.d, aggregates.total
from days
left join aggregates on days.d = aggregates.d
order by days.d;
```

It's easiest and most readable if you put `group by` in a subquery and then left join that subquery to days. You can also add more subqueries and join them to have more aggregates, even from different source tables, in same table.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still getting the same result (IE just values for d = 1,2,3)

Comment: Right. I edited the answer after realizing my mistake.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)